# python ElementTree - find value of child's attribute based on parent's attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

Here is a example of what's in my XML file.

```
<parent    uniqueID="1000" name="Bob Ross"   >
    <child     atrribute1="value"
</parent>
```

The user is going to search for a uniqueID and the program will return various bits of information.

Using element tree I get return the value of the 'name' in parent using this

```
x = root.find("./parent[@uniqueID='"+entered_text+"']").attrib['name']
```

I would like to get the child's element 'attribute1' based on the uniqueID the user has search for. I am just not sure how to do it.

I have been searching and looking through the documentation, however I am quite new to python and element tree so I may have missed it.

Many thanks,
bozogs

Answer (score 2):

Typical I work it out after posting on here - here is the answer for anyone who stumbles across this question

Using the Xpath you just add another / on as it's already looking at the parent.

```
root.find(".//parent[@uniqueID='" + entered_text + "']/child").attrib['attribute1']
```

Comment: I was about to say that! Good that you figured it out. You can also just get the parent-element with `x = root.find(".//parent[@uniqueID='" + entered_text + "']]")`. Then the child-elements can be found by indexing the parent, so the child-element would be `child = x[0]`, and you can do what you already did: `attribute1 = child.attrib['attribute1']`.